# What is this error?

Tags: android

I have an app on ***google play*** on my phone  sometimes when I open my app it waits more time on white screen and doesnot open then turn black screen and give error.(**it does not say wait or force close**) When I report that bug to ***google play.*** I copy and paste error log below,(there is no any hint to understand what happens) 
Thanks in advance!
(my app calls webservice in the beginning is this a problem ? I mean if a network connection is weak then this occurs for that?)

**Native Crash**

```
*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
Build fingerprint: 'lge/g2_open_com/g2:4.4.2/KOT49I.D80220a/D802**a.13***70**0:user/release-keys'
Revision: '10'
pid: 9780, tid: 9780, name: ub.twostrangers >>> com.wub.twostrangers <<<
signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL), fault addr --------
r0 417bd3b0 r1 00000080 r2 ffffd1b4 r3 00000000
r4 417bd3b0 r5 417bd3a0 r6 ffffd1b4 r7 000000f0
r8 00000000 r9 00000000 sl 00000000 fp 438443d0
ip 00000000 sp beec73d0 lr 4005f0d8 pc 40071b38 cpsr 680f0010
d0 0000000000000000 d1 0000000000000000
d2 0000000000000000 d3 0000000000000000
d4 412e848000000000 d5 3ff0000000000000
d6 412e848000000000 d7 4000000000000000
d8 0000000000000000 d9 0000000000000000
d10 0000000000000000 d11 0000000000000000
d12 0000000000000000 d13 0000000000000000
d14 0000000000000000 d15 0000000000000000
d16 0000000000000000 d17 0000000000000000
d18 3ff0000000000000 d19 412e848000000000
d20 4f494e5520617461 d21 fffffffffffffffe
d22 4000000000000000 d23 412e848000000000
d24 43e0000000000000 d25 3ff0000000000000
d26 3ff0000000000000 d27 0000000500000000
d28 547d42aea2879f2e d29 0000000100000001
d30 4024000000000000 d31 3ff0000000000000
scr 80000012

backtrace:
#00 pc 00021b38 /system/lib/libc.so (__futex_syscall3+8)
#01 pc 0000f0d4 /system/lib/libc.so (__pthread_cond_timedwait_relative+48)
#02 pc 0000f134 /system/lib/libc.so (__pthread_cond_timedwait+64)
#03 pc 00055f77 /system/lib/libdvm.so
#04 pc 0006a8b1 /system/lib/libdvm.so
#05 pc 00029960 /system/lib/libdvm.so
#06 pc 00030ec8 /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmMterpStd(Thread*)+76)
#07 pc 0002e560 /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmInterpret(Thread*, Method const*, JValue*)+184)
#08 pc 00063a79 /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmInvokeMethod(Object*, Method const*, ArrayObject*, ArrayObject*, ClassObject*, bool)+392)
#09 pc 0006b943 /system/lib/libdvm.so
#10 pc 00029960 /system/lib/libdvm.so
#11 pc 00030ec8 /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmMterpStd(Thread*)+76)
#12 pc 0002e560 /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmInterpret(Thread*, Method const*, JValue*)+184)
#13 pc 00063795 /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallMethodV(Thread*, Method const*, Object*, bool, JValue*, std::__va_list)+336)
#14 pc 0004ce97 /system/lib/libdvm.so
#15 pc 0004decf /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so
#16 pc 0004ec27 /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (android::AndroidRuntime::start(char const*, char const*)+354)
#17 pc 0000109b /system/bin/app_process
#18 pc 0000e55b /system/lib/libc.so (__libc_init+50)
#19 pc 00000db0 /system/bin/app_process

code around pc:
40071b18 e5900000 e2601000 e0100001 116f0f10 
40071b28 12600020 e12fff1e e1a0c007 e3a070f0 
40071b38 ef000000 e1a0700c e12fff1e eafffff9 
40071b48 e1a0c007 e1a03002 e1a02001 e3a01000 
40071b58 e3a070f0 ef000000 e1a0700c e12fff1e 
40071b68 e1a0c007 e1a02001 e3a01001 e3a070f0 
40071b78 ef000000 e1a0700c e12fff1e e1a0000d 
40071b88 e12fff1e e92d50f0 e3a07025 ef000000 
40071b98 e8bd50f0 e3700a01 912fff1e e2600000 
40071ba8 ea006fc5 f5d0f000 f5d1f000 e1500001 
40071bb8 13520000 03a00000 012fff1e e1a03000 
40071bc8 e352000c 5a000008 f5d0f020 f5d1f020 
40071bd8 e0d300b2 e0d1c0b2 e050000c 112fff1e 
40071be8 e2522001 1afffff9 e12fff1e e92d4010 
40071bf8 e3130002 0a000005 e0d300b2 e0d1c0b2 
40071c08 e2422001 e050000c 18bd4010 112fff1e 

code around lr:
4005f0b8 e1a07002 ebfffe8b e5941000 e1a03007 
4005f0c8 e1a02006 e2011001 e1a00004 ebfffd5f 
4005f0d8 e1a04000 e1a00005 ebfffe41 e374006e 
4005f0e8 03a0006e 13a00000 e8bd80f8 e3520000 
4005f0f8 e92d4030 e1a05000 e24dd00c e1a04001 
4005f108 0a000007 e1a01002 e1a0000d e1a02003 
4005f118 ebfffd12 e3500000 b3a0006e ba000003 
4005f128 e1a0200d e1a00005 e1a01004 ebffffda 
4005f138 e28dd00c e8bd8030 e3a03000 eaffffea 
4005f148 e3a02000 eafffffb e3a03001 eaffffe6 
4005f158 eaffffd1 e304cdd3 e341c062 e92d4010 
4005f168 e1a0e002 e084329c e3043240 e340300f 
4005f178 e24dd008 e1a0200d e1a0c324 e3a04ffa 
4005f188 e58dc000 e06eec94 e0030e93 e58d3004 
4005f198 ebffffc1 e28dd008 e8bd8010 e5903000 
4005f1a8 e92d4070 e3130002 e1a04000 e1a05001
```

Comment: when and how u got this dude

Comment: When I want to open my app , it gives white screen , after 1 mins it gives error

Comment: what task u do on that time

Comment: it is possible that your application hangs during initialization and OS simply kills it.

Comment: @OlegEstekhin what you mean ? my app hangs? , thanks for reply

Comment: in the begining I call my own service , then it calls my webservice to check somethings, but this error occurs sometimes not always

Comment: Your error log makes no meaningful sense. Post logcat output and also code.

Comment: by the way it says native crash , what is it ?

Answer (score 2):

You are performing a long-running task in the main thread. Sometimes that task finishes before timeout and your application unfreezes, sometimes it does not and system kills your application.

You should move that task into a separate thread or into an `AsyncTask`. You should read [Processes and Threads](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html) section as the starting point.

Comment: I use `AsyncTask` in my service but I use **.get()** so it should be the problem? because sometimes my network connection is weak. I try it without **.get()** so it does its work on background , I try this and turn back

Comment: by the way it says native crash , what is it ?

Comment: `AsynkTask.get()` blocks the current thread until the task is complete. You need to override `onPostExecute` or `onProgressUpdate` to pass the data from the task into the main thread.

Comment: @OlegEstekhin Why does it produce a native crash? In such case you say it should throw an exception.